# What does the word "wähh" mean?

Tags: standard-german, swiss-standard-german

> Der ganze Fisch mit Kopf und Augen, das sieht so wähh aus!

The "wähh" word over here is just an expression or has some meaning to it?

Also, is it a positive or negative expression?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is answered [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/German/comments/bau4hy/can_someone_help_me_with_the_meaning_of_this/).

Comment: Are you sure it is not 'bäh' instead of 'wäh'?

Comment: "Wähh" ist kein Wort, sondern Lautmalerei.

Comment: Additional information: the sentence appears as part of a longer dialogue in one of the spoken exercises in the German as a Second Langauge textbook "Netzwerk A2.1" published by Klett.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

"Wäh", or "wähh" or similar is a colloquial term for expressing disgust. The talker means that the fish looks disgusting.

Comment: Think "eww"... I would probably reevaluate my relationship to whoever uses this for food after the age of 17.

Comment: The Germany standard German equivalent would be _igitt._

Comment: @mach Do you just mean not standard because of the informality, or is it not used colloquially in (some regions in ) Germany?

Comment: @HalvarF If they use it as an adjective, I concur. As an interjection, I find it pretty normal.

Comment: The closest thing I could find in Wiktionary or DWDS is *Wähe*, which, I gather, is a regional name for some kind of pastry. If *wäh* was worthy of a dictionary entry then I'd happy to go ahead and add it to Wiktionary, but  the evidence I've seen is rather skimpy. Wiktionary does have an entry for "ew" and one or two variants, but I think it's more frequently used than *wäh*.

Comment: Strange, maybe it's something regional, but I would never have used "wäh" to express disgust, I think "bäh" is much more common (see https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/b%C3%A4h). For me "wäh" is more the sound of a baby crying...

Comment: @rob74: I would regularly hear that, and not only from children. But probably only in the local dialect.

Comment: @phipsgabler: I have not said the word is non-standard. Like all interjections, it is rather informal. Also, it appears to be a regional word. Nonetheless, it certainly belongs to standard German, see my response.

Answer (score 10):

The word *wäh* (not *bäh* or *uäh,* but *wäh)* is an interjection for expressing disgust. Like all interjections, it is colloquial to a certain degree. Nonetheless, it is a well attested word with a specific form and meaning. It is common in Switzerland. I do not know whether it is also used in other regions – it probably is.

The absence of *wäh* from common dictionaries or wordbooks suggests that it is not well known in Germany. The absence is rather scandalous since the word is well attested. However, the absence not unusual. Dictionaries and wordbooks tend to have a strong bias towards Germany – like the bias many English dictionaries used to have towards Britain a century ago. The Germany German equivalent would be *igitt,* which is found in dictionaries, though it also appears to be a regional word – it feels foreign in Switzerland.

The word *wäh* is even attested in the NZZ, one of the most respected German language newspapers, cf. articles like the following:

- [Überwachung für liegengebliebenen Abfall](https://www.nzz.ch/panorama/alltagsgeschichten/ueberwachung-fuer-liegengebliebenen-abfall-in-zug-1.18557063): «Wäh! So nicht!»
- [Wae gook in](https://www.nzz.ch/wae_gook_in-1.12303402): «Nach alldem fühlt sich der Fremde dann doch ziemlich wäh.»
- [Zehn Kilo Fett gegen Fettleibigkeit](https://www.nzz.ch/zehn_kilo_fett_gegen_fettleibigkeit-1.657371): «Fett ist ‹wäh›.»
- [Voll schwul, Mann](https://www.nzz.ch/voll_schwul_mann-1.702393): «‹Dort. Er hat die Beine rasiert.› – ‹Wäh.›»
- [«Selbstbewusstsein schützt am besten vor Essstörungen»](https://www.nzz.ch/wissenschaft/bildung/selbstbewusstsein-schuetzt-am-besten-vor-essstoerungen-1.18493219): «Vor allem Lebensmittel mit starken Geschmäcken, also Scharfes, Saures und Bitteres, ist einfach mal ‹wäh-gruusig›.»
- [Ski unheil](https://www.nzz.ch/ski-unheil-1.17973853): «Wäh! Kann ich nicht.»
- [«Buah, eine Echse! - Darf ich sie halten?»](https://www.nzz.ch/article7Q8SH-1.488012): «‹Buah!›, ‹Wäh!› und immer noch ‹Yöh!› lauten die Kommentare.»
- [Am Anfang war der Sex – nur warum fehlen uns dafür die Worte?](https://www.nzz.ch/gesellschaft/sex-warum-fehlen-uns-die-worte-dafuer-ld.1438756): «Ich dachte: ‹Wäh!›», sagt Schmid.»

You could go on and find it in other Swiss newspapers that have less international prestige, but this already proves that it is a Swiss standard German word.

Comment: Thanks for this answer (+1). I had no idea that this is common in Switzerland. It definitely isn't (in that sense) anywhere that I lived (Northern/Western Germany), but it also reminded me of having heard that from someone from Konstanz am Bodensee.

Answer (score 7):

The forms *bäh, uäh* are [interjections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interjection) expressing disgust, in this case transcribed as *wähh**. [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/baeh) has *bäh*: *Ausruf des Ekels*.

<sub>* One feature that distinguishes interjections from normal words is that the spelling is not necessarily fixed; see for instance pages 16–20 in [this ruleset](https://ids-pub.bsz-bw.de/frontdoor/deliver/index/docId/9326/file/Winterscheid_etal._Normalisierungskonventionen_2019.pdf) used in the transcription of voice recordings.</sub>

One thing stands out in the given example:

> Der Fisch sieht so wähh aus!

Interjections are usually used independently. But in this instance, the interjection is used within a sentence like a normal adjective (e.g. *eklig*): modified by *so* and functioning as the complement of *aussehen*. I would associate this usage more with children or teenagers than adults.

As far as the phonetic form is concerned, there seems to be a certain amount of [iconicity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iconicity), although, as in all such cases, it is not quite certain what the precise connection between form and meaning is: The opening of the lips when producing *bäh* reminds me of spitting, whereas I connect *uäh* with the sound of vomiting.

Since Duden only has *bäh*, not *uäh*, I took a look at the [Deutsches Referenzkorpus](https://www1.ids-mannheim.de/kl/projekte/korpora.html?L=0) and found two nice examples:

> Ich musste immer die Nieren putzen, waschen, schneiden, uäh. Das kann ich nicht ab. (die tageszeitung, 17.06.2017)

> "Das ist voll gruselig", erzählte sie laut, "da stehen Hunderte Mumien herum. Ein paar sind schon richtig vergammelt - uäh! […]" (Berliner Zeitung, 03.06.2009)

Comment: One cannot expect that these words have a standard spelling recorded in the Duden. "uäh", "wäh" (or "wähh") have a more or less identical sound. Concerning "bäh" : Duden mentions as the 2. meaning "lautmalend für das Blöken des Schafes". This is an obvious correspondence to my interpretation of "wähh" as "lautmalend für das Weinen von Kindern". But it also shows that, depending on the context, there is a difference between "bäh" and "wäh".

Answer (score 2):

As PMF explains in his answer, in the context of your question "wähh" expresses disgust. However, it is also used to ape weeping children. A nice example can be found [here](https://www.play3.de/2010/08/06/quartalsergebnis-activision-blizzard-mit-166-mio-euro-gewinn/) as the comment of the user *fuschi*:

> Wähh wähh wähh! Uns gehts so schlecht. Wir müssen unfertige Spiele veröffentlichen, um DLC zu verticken. Wir müssen Project 10 $ und DayOneDLC einführen. Wir müssen den Multiplayer besteuern. Wähh wähh wähh! Wir leben an der Existenzgrenze!

Here are more examples found via Google:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I wrote more or less the same in a comment to PMF's answer. But then I noticed the "swiss-standard-german" tag - maybe the Swiss use "wäh" to express disgust?

Comment: @rob74  Interesting, I didn't take notice of the tag  "swiss-standard-german".  Certainly there may be regional differences in the use of "wääh", but I think it is quite common in Germany to express disgust by "wähh" and, as you say, "bähh". Perhaps "wääh" is an onomatopoeic word for the sound of vomiting.

Comment: I didn't notice the tag either, but it confuses me a bit. It should probably be "swiss-german" instead (which is something quite different than "swiss-standard-german"). If Swiss use standard german, they usually don't use these kind of coloquial terms (as it is considered a formal language).